# Fixed colorange for making plots using matplotlibs

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I am currently trying to visualize some dataset with matplotlib, but seem to have some problems with the color range.

The way I am currently making my plots is a following:

```
def make_plot_store_data(name,interweaved,static):
    Y =  np.array(range(0,static.shape[1]))
    X =  np.array(range(0,static.shape[0]))
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

    plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,np.log10(static.T),cmap=cm.jet)
    plt.xlabel('Frames')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency(Hz)')
    plt.title('Power spectrum of ' + name)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.savefig(plot+"/"+name+"_plot_static_conv.png")
    plt.close()
```

Problems with plotting it this way is that the colorbar automatically adjust to the dataset, which is not wanted.

I want a constant colorbar/fixed color bar such that i avoid representation such this:

[image]

In which darkred = >18

and here it is:

[image]

is darkred = >2.5

I am trying to do pattern recognition, and I think this is somehow messing up with my result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the min and max color levels using **vmin** and **vmax**:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,100,0.2)
y = np.arange(0,40,0.2)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.random.random((y.shape[0],x.shape[0]))*np.sin(0.01*X*Y)


plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z, cmap=plt.cm.jet, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]